# Android: NullPointerException en .getIntent().getExtras()

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Estoy en un proyecto de clase de android y lo tengo casi terminado pero necesito pasar unas variables de una actividad a otra, me da NullPointerException y buscando no he encontrado nada.

> Logcat
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
>                                                                              at com.grupo3.cebancburger.AnadirHamburguesa.(AnadirHamburguesa.java:31)

El intent que yo hago en la clase.

MainActivity:

(Las vistas)

```
nomb = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nombre);
dire = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.direccion);
tele = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.telefono);
email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
```

(Intent)

```
intent = new Intent(DatosCliente.this, AnadirHamburguesa. 
intent.putExtra("nombre", nomb.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra("direccion", dire.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra("telefono", tele.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra("email", email.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

AnadirHamburguesa(el getIntent)

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String nom = extras.getString("nombre");
String dire = extras.getString("direccion");
String tele = extras.getString("telefono");
String email = extras.getString("email");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intenta recuperar la información en tu actividad AnadirHamburguesa sin utilizar Bundle, de la siguiente forma

AnadirHamburguesa

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String nombre = intent.getStringExtra("nombre");
String dire = intent.getStringExtra("direccion");    
...
```

Si usas Bundle para pasar datos debes crear el Bundle y pasarlo en el intent

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
Intent intent = new Intent(DatosCliente.this, AnadirHamburguesa.class)
bundle.putString("nombre",nombre);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

En AnadirHamburguesa

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String nom = extras.getString("nombre");
```

En un futuro intenta usar Parcelable o Serializable para pasar objetos de una actividad a otra.
Por ejemplo si tienes un objeto de tipo Cliente que implementa  la clase Parcelable

```
Cliente cliente = new Cliente(nombre,direccion);

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(, SigActividad.class);
intent.putExtra("cliente", cliente);
startActivity(intent);
```

En SigActividad:

```
Cliente cliente = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("nombre");
...
```

Comment: Voy a intentarlo, aun así no creo que ese sea el problema.

Comment: Verifica la edición de mi respuesta. Si usas Bundle debes crearlo y pasarlo también el intent. Prueba ambas opciones (con y sin bundle) a ver cual te funciona mejor

Comment: No me deja hacer un putExtra(bundle), ¿Como lo hago exactamente?

Comment: Perdón es:  intent.putExtra("bundle",bundle) y pon los datos  en el bundle: bundle.putString("key",value)

Comment: Me sigue diciendo que es null, no entiendo por qué

Comment: Lo acabo de probar en un proyecto de Android. Al pasar el bundle por el intent es intent.putExtras(bundle) (extras, no extra ). Me funcionó sin problemas. Corrijo mi respuesta

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71549/discussion-between-carlos-cardoso-and-aritzbn).

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda en el chat, te valoro de forma positiva ya que creo que estas opciones son muy valibles y me valdrán para futuros proyectos, de verdad, muchísimas gracias.